# Uses of Electronic Filters?

Tags: filter, power-electronics, semiconductors

Can anyone tell the real life examples of electronic filters? Why do we need them ? Whey do we need certain range of frequencies while others are rejected ? Sorry i am new in electronics so please do not mind.

Comment: Radios, speaker crossover networks...

Comment: Listening to all radio stations at once would probably drive you crazy.

Comment: so all radio stations send different frequencies and filters provide which we need ? @BrianDrummond

Comment: Also, tone control for amplifiers.

Answer (score 1):

It is an extremely vast topic. Also, an extremely important one.
It's a whole field of study within electrical engineering.

> Why do we need certain range of frequencies while others are rejected ?

Depends on the specific situation.

For instance, if you're building a radio, a big part of the whole spectrum is occupied, so you need to select a narrow portion to be able to hear a single radio station.

In another context you may need to eliminate as much electronic noise as you can, so you can have a "clean" signal.

Or you may have a system that is on most of the time, but inevitably turns off every X seconds for a very short time, but you may just wanna know if it is on or off "on the long term".

These are just sparse examples intended to spark your curiosity. If you're interested, have fun taking your time to learn this wonderfully interesting area of technology.

Comment: all radio stations send different frequencies and we need to filter them to listen a particular channels ? @electrical architect ?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.